# Change navigation item text, body element and navigation style on click (JS, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a simple navigation bar:

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html">Game</a>
            <a href="help.html">Help</a>
            <a href=#>Dark</a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And I want to, using jQuery, switch to dark mode on menu item click (change background to black, menu items to white, and replace the text "Dark" to "Light"). Basically when you click on "Dark" in the navigation bar, it switches to the described dark mode, then it changes to light when you click on "Light", which is the new name for that menu item.

Comment: Cool, can you share the javascript you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a selector to the anchor tag to make sure you are binding the method in document.ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggleTheme').click(function() {
    var currentObj=$(this);
    if(!currentObj.hasClass("changeBg")){
       $('body').addClass('newbg')
       currentObj.text('Light').addClass('changeBg');
    }
    else{
       $('body').removeClass('newbg');
       currentObj.text('Dark').removeClass('changeBg'); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.newbg{
  background:yellow
}
.oldbg{
  background:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href="index.html">Game</a>
        <a href="help.html">Help</a>
        <a href="#" id="toggleTheme">Dark</a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried this and the previous answer, but they don't seem to be working for some reason. I tried putting the class for ul to be "changeBg"

Comment: @Mina could you explain is it not working where>

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the menu item

Comment: we can connect over some webex aur teams if you want

Comment: Can I just send you a link to a google doc with the full code and you can edit what's wrong?

Comment: yes as u wish. mukeshsingh.negi007@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you! I added you to the doc

Comment: @Mina sent you via email.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to give a class name for your link.

Get the event and check if the link has class Dark or not.

Then change background and add or remove dark class name

```js
// get the click on the link with themeSwitcher class
$('.themeSwitcher').click(function() {
  // if the link dont have dark class
  if (!$(this).parents('ul').hasClass('dark')) {
    $('body').css('background-color', '#000');
    $(this).text('Light');
    $(this).parents('ul').removeClass('light').addClass('dark');
  } else {
    // else we switch to white
    $('body').css('background-color', '#fff');
    $(this).text('Dark');
    $(this).parents('ul').removeClass('dark').addClass('light');  
  }
});
```

```css
.light a { color:#000 }
.dark a { color:#fff }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul class="light">
        <a href="index.html">Game</a>
        <a href="help.html">Help</a>
        <a href="#" class="themeSwitcher">Dark</a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, but where do I put the 'dark' or 'light' class? I tried it in the <a> element but it's not working

Comment: @Mina you need to put the class to the ul instead of the link then. Please, validate my answer if i answered your question

Comment: I don't know why but nothing happens when I click on it, not even with the edited answer

Comment: Nothing happens ?